# How to return to default view in a file you got elsewhere

Tags: customization

I have gotten several files from various sources on the net to learn from. When they load the UI is completely changed from what I am used to in the Default view when you first create a new blender scene.

I am looking at the file now and there is no default view selection anyway in it. Since I am very new to blender I like to use the default view that is standard with blender as it helps me find things I need.

[image]

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Fine then I have not been able to do it with the answers here then you can delete this post and I will go else where. Sorry for taking up your time with my question